# Exporting the data points from two plotted curves

Tags: export, output-formatting, text

I am using Wolfram Mathematica 11. Given these quantities:

```
v = 3; 
Y = Sqrt[v^2 - X^2];

Ja = BesselJ[0, X]; 
Jap = -BesselJ[1, X];

Ka = BesselK[0, Y]; 
Kap = -BesselK[1, Y];

side1 = Jap / (X*Ja); 
side2 = -Kap / (Y*Ka);
```

I would like to obtain the same visual output as:

```
Plot[{side1, side2}, {X, 0, 10}]
```

but on a `.txt` file, simply containing a table of values in this notation:

```
 0.0000000000e+00 -inf -inf
 3.0060120240e-02 -2.3042094212e+00 -2.1217639107e+01
 6.0120240481e-02 -1.8613440179e+00 -1.0654661322e+01
```

First column should list the `X` values; second column should list the corresponding `side1` values; third column the corresponding `side2` values.

How is it possible, with and without adaptive sampling?

**Important note**: I am not obliged to use `Plot`. I would like to obtain a `.txt` output file with the lines in the same format as above. The way it is created (through `Plot` or *any* other suitable function) is not important.

---

**Edit**: I obtained two separate tables (in the desired format) this way:

```
pts1 = Cases[Plot[side1[X], {X, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-1.6, 1.6}], Line[data_] :> data, All]~Flatten~1; Export["file1.txt",pts1,"Table"]

pts2 = Cases[Plot[side2[X], {X, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-1.6, 1.6}], Line[data_] :> data, All]~Flatten~1; Export["file2.txt",pts2,"Table"]
```

Thanks to @MarcoB for his suggestions in the comments. Each file has only two columns. Note that `file1.txt` spans from `X = 0` to `X = 10`, while `file2.txt` from `X = 0` to `X = 1.778`, for the reasons pointed out by @m_golberg.

I was looking for a single table. This solution instead would demand to the external reader, which uses the table, the task to correctly overlap the two tables. This was **not** my initial intention, but if this is the only way, it is acceptable as well.

Comment: Your code based on extracting data points from `Plot` is a good idea to exploit its adaptive sampling. When adapting code, though, it is always a good idea to test it step by step. For instance, if you ran just `Plot[side1@X, {X, 0, 10}]`, you would have realized that it returned an empty plot. Indeed, `side` is not a function in your code, so it does not make sense to apply it to `X`. Instead, use `Plot[side1, {X, 0, 10}]`. Then `Cases[Plot[side1, {X, 0, 10}], Line[data_] :> data, All]~Flatten~1` will give you a list of points including all four branches of the `side1` function.

Comment: @MarcoB I tried as suggested, but I obtained exactly the opposite. `Plot[side1@X, {X, 0, 10}]` prints the function `side1`, while `Plot[side1, {X, 0, 10}]` generates an empty plot. Consequently, `Cases[Plot[side1, {X, 0, 10}], Line[data_] :> data, All]~Flatten~1` gives an empty output.

Comment: @MarcoB Instead, `Cases[Plot[side1, {X, 0, 10}], Line[data_] :> data, All]~Flatten~1` produces the desired output, with all the branches as you said (and this would deserve a dedicated answer below). Maybe you made a typo in your comment?

Answer (score 2):

You might make a table as follows

```
lst1 = Table[{X, side1}, {X, 0.01, 10, 0.1}];
```

then transform the numbers into a format you need:

```
lst2 = lst1 // 
   NumberForm[#, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#, "e", #3}] &), 
     ExponentFunction -> (# &)] &;
```

and export it:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "file.txt", lst2, "Table"]
```

Do not forget to first save your notebook somewhere, to enable `NotebookDirectory[]` work.

Have fun!

Comment: First of all, thank you. Apparently I have `lst1` and `lst2` equal in my code, so the output file has not the correct format. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? I also tried to put `lst2 = lst1 // NumberForm ...` all in the same line, but with no improvements.

Comment: Why do not you do exactly as I did. It worked for me, and should also work for you.

Comment: I did as you did: this is a [screenshot](https://ibb.co/x31HHBn) and this is the [output](https://pastebin.com/KpT2hcAK). Values in text file are not arranged as in the 3 sample line I posted in the question.